# Complex Flex Dashboard Layout

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to make a flex dashboard with a somewhat complicated layout (at least more complicated than the examples on the website!). Here is my attempted layout and a picture of roughly what I"m going for:

```
Inputs{.sidebar}
[input code]
Column {data-width = 660}
### title1 {.value-box}
[title1 code]
### title2 {.value-box}
[title2 code]
### title3
[title3 code]
Column {data-width = 340}
### title4
[title4 code]
```

And here is what I'm going for:
[image]

What's happening currently is that the value boxes are stacking on top of each other and the column with title4 is the same width as the middle column.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you have the `orientation` and `vertical_layout` parameters set in the header YAML?

Comment: `orientation:columns`
`vertical_layout:fill`

Comment: I think maybe the ability to right justify a second sidebar would do the trick. Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You can make one column for the sidebar, one for the main panels, and one for `title4`, but you can't combine row and column layouts (yet), so there's a way (AFAIK, anyway) to position the `valuebox`es next to each other, which is, yes, a little silly.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451484/how-to-combine-row-and-column-layout-in-flexdashboard) can help ?

Comment: Yeah that one is interesting/helpful but for the fact that you can't have two sidebars :/ I tried and they ended up stacked on top of one another

Comment: [JJ says](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/87#issuecomment-245585329) the ability to make arrangements like this is coming eventually through the use of h4 headers, but not soon.

Comment: I had a similar task, but with 3 value boxes. Haven't found the good solution and ended up with plotting necessary text with ggplot2. Here is a [project](https://sobukhov.shinyapps.io/Prices/). Click "Source Code" at the upper right corner. Lines 125-142 put the text and figures on the blank plot.
You may also play with rectangles, colors, fonts, and sizes to make upper block looks like value boxes. Hope this helps!