# How to display multiple plots on an R flexdashboard page if using storyboard layout

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I'm building an R FlexDashboard in storyboard format. I'd like to display multiple plots on a few of the storyboard pages, including a series of linked plots using crosstalk. However, when I try to display multiple plots on a page or use the bscols() function, the page looks all messed up. Are multiple plots allowed in R FlexDashboard's storyboard format? Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Error_example"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    theme: bootstrap
---

###Example: Why can't won't the datatable show up below the plot in this storyboard?

```{r}
library(plotly)
library(DT)

plot1<-plot_ly(data=diamonds,x=~carat,y=~price)
table1<-datatable(diamonds)

plot1
table1
````

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: Edit: Just added a code sample

Answer (score 7):

`bsCols()` Seems to completely override the flexdashboard CSS so I would avoid using that.

A simple solution would be to add some divs into the R chunk. Something like:

````
---
title: "I think this should work"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true
    theme: bootstrap
---

###Example: Using divs to separate outputs

```{r}
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(DT)

plot1<-plot_ly(data=diamonds,x=~carat,y=~price)
table1<-datatable(diamonds)

 tags$div(
   tags$div(
    plot1
  ),
  tags$div(
    table1
  )
 )
```
````

Answer (score 3):

This example combines crosstalk, leaflet and plotly, in a way which allows for a high number of plots. The trick is to use absolutepanels with collapsable buttons. The absolutepanel sits over the leaflet map, which means the map can be full size like in superzip https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html, while the buttons allow plots to appear on an as needs basis. So you can add as many plots and tables as youe like, link them with crosstalk, and still tell your story.

[image]

[image]

This makes a clean interface where plots are included in a way which the user has greater control over the final display. Another example is here [How to combine row and column layout in flexdashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451484/how-to-combine-row-and-column-layout-in-flexdashboard), but without crosstalk.

````
    ---
    title: "Demo"
    output:
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: columns
        vertical_layout: fill
    ---


    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(rmarkdown)
    library(plotly)
    library(shiny)
    library(DT)

    ```


    ```{r}
    library(crosstalk)
    sd <- SharedData$new(quakes[sample(nrow(quakes), 100),])

    ```


    Map { data-icon="fa-map-o"}
    =====================================  
    Sidebar {.sidebar data-width=220}
    --------------------------------

    ```{r, results='asis'}

     filter_slider("mag", "Magnitude", sd, column=~mag, step=0.1, width=200)

    ```

    Column {data-width=400}
    --------------------------------


    ### Planet Earth

    ```{r}

    library(leaflet)
     leaflet(sd) %>% addTiles() %>% addMarkers()

    ```



    ```{r}
    ##########################
    absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                  draggable = TRUE, top = 70, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
                  width = '25%', height = 'auto', 
                  style = "overflow-y:scroll; max-height: 1000px; opacity: 0.9; style = z-index: 400",

                h4(strong("Plot Explorer")),

        HTML('<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box1" class="btn-block btn-primary">dot plot</button>'),
        tags$div(id = 'box1', class="collapse in",

         plot_ly(sd, x = ~depth, y = ~mag) %>% layout(height=200)

                ),

     HTML('<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box2" class="btn-block btn-warning">histogram</button>'),
        tags$div(id = 'box2', class="collapse",

           plot_ly(sd, x = ~depth, y = ~mag, type = "histogram", name = "Histogram") %>% layout(height=200)
        ),

      HTML('<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#box3" class="btn-block btn-danger">table</button>'),
        tags$div(id = 'box3', class="collapse in",

     datatable(sd, extensions="Scroller", style="bootstrap", class="compact", width="100%",height = 300,
        options=list(deferRender=TRUE, scrollY=300, scroller=TRUE))
       )

      )

    ```
````