# How to increase height of tabset in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I'm trying to increase/override the default height of the containers of the tabset containers using flexdashboard as they are currently too small. Is there a way to increase/override the height of the containers in the tabset using flexdashboard?

Here is the overall layout code for the flexdashboard:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}

```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

          
```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}

    
```

{.tabset .tabset-fade}
-------------------------------------

### Table 1
```{r}

```


### Table 2
```{r}
````

I believe I have to use {data-height=650} but when I include this in the code it doesn't increase the container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R markdown - flexdashboard - grid layout & scroll & tabset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48702343/r-markdown-flexdashboard-grid-layout-scroll-tabset)

Comment: No unfortunately.